# How can I install opencsv lib in eclipse (Ubuntu)

Tags: installation, opencsv

I know this question is stupid, I searched very hard but still cannot find a solution.

Here is the thing: I downloaded the source code of opencsv with libs (its file name is:opencsv-2.3-src-with-libs.tar.gz), and tried to import it to my android project (under Ubuntu eclipse). As far as I found out, I cannot import any file as lib if it is not end with *.jar, while there is only one .jar file in the package, and sadly is junit-4.7.jar, it seems has nothing to do with opencsv. I'm seriously confused...

Please tell me how to import the tar.gz file as a library, really really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

% tar xfvz opencsv-2.3-src-with-libs.tar.gz
% cd opencsv-2.3/deploy
% ls
you'll find "open-csv-2.3.jar"